# Get a word with its value

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Is there a way to extract a word with its value in a dictionary-like file like the following ones?

File contents:

```
"foo":1234,"bar":123
```

Or

```
foo:1234,bar:123
```

I only need `foo:1234`

Comment: In which language? What is your file type?

Comment: @Charles-olivierDemers Is a .txt, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If the input file is a json you can use this

```
jq .foo file
```

else you can use this

```
grep -Po 'foo[\"]?:\K[^,]+' file
```